# How to make a <span></span> tag go to the right as far as possible?

Tags: html, css

How to make a `<span></span>` tag goes to the right as possible using CSS without the use of `margin` nor `padding`?

Not this way :

```
<span style="margin-left:1000px;">ABC</span>
```

Comment: In what context? What have you tried? To the right as possible of what?

Comment: A little bit of context wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @JohnTobin, of a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float:right
```

Generally speaking, unless your css has explicitly made a style class for it, such as Bootstrap, you may add `right` in your class or `pull-right`

```
<span class="mySpan">something</span>
.mySpan{ float:right}
```

General answer for a general question. If you have something more complicated, post your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `float: right` CSS property. See some more documentation here:

[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
```